# CRA showing installments payable for 2019 even if I am getting a refund

Tags: income-tax, canada, canada-revenue-agency

When I filed my 2018 tax returns  in Ontario, it shows that I am getting a refund; but then it hows Total instalment payable in 2019: XXX $.
If I don't owe any taxes in 2018, why does it show instalments payable?

Comment: Sorry, please see edit.